# How to implement a Gson equivalent of @JsonUnwrap

Tags: java, json, gson

I know Gson doesn't come with a similar feature, but is there a way to add support for unwrapping Json fields the way `@JsonUnwrap` does?

The goal is to allow a structure like:

```
public class Person { 
    public int age; 
    public Name name; 
} 

public class Name { 
    public String first;
    public String last; 
}
```

to be (de)serialized as:

```
{
  "age" : 18, 
  "first" : "Joey", 
  "last" : "Sixpack" 
}
```

instead of:

```
{
   "age" : 18, 
    "name" : {
        "first" : "Joey",
        "last" : "Sixpack"
    } 
 }
```

I understand it could get fairly complex, so I'm not looking for a full solution, just some high-level guidelines if this is even doable.

Comment: What if you had a recursive subclass? Like a LinkedList

Comment: You'd have to have a way to beak the recursion, like Jackson does. Or you'd simply not use this in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no easy way to do that. Here are anyway some pointers/alternative ways to make it work.

---

**GsonFire**: [GsonFire](https://github.com/julman99/gson-fire) implements some useful features missing from Gson. While it does not yet offer automatic wrapping/unwrapping, it may be a good starting point to create your custom logic.

If you *only need serialization*, you can add getters for `first` and `last` in `Person` and use [`@ExposeMethodResult`](https://github.com/julman99/gson-fire#expose-your-methods) to serialize them. Unfortunately, setters are not supported (cf. [Is possible to use setters when Gson deserializes a JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660334/is-possible-to-use-setters-when-gson-deserializes-a-json)).

---

Another way to support the serialization is to follow the advices from [How to move fields to parent object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898914/gson-how-to-move-fields-to-parent-object).

---

**Custom TypeAdapters** : on of the only ways to support both serialization and deserialization is to create custom `TypeAdapter`s. This won't be generic, but it will suit your usecase.

The thread [Serialize Nested Object as Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350183/gson-serialize-nested-object-as-attributes) already gives you examples, so I won't repeat them here.

Comment: OP already found GsonFire https://github.com/julman99/gson-fire/issues/32

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, that's me. Opened it just before asking.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a crude implementation of a deserializer that supports this. It is fully generic (type-independent), but also expensive and fragile and I will not be using it for anything serious. I am posting only to show to others what I've got, if they end up needing to do something similar.

```
public class UnwrappingDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    //This Gson needs to be identical to the global one, sans this deserializer to prevent infinite recursion
    private Gson delegate;

    public UnwrappingDeserializer(Gson delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Object def = delegate.fromJson(json, type); //Gson doesn't care about unknown fields
        Class raw = GenericTypeReflector.erase(type);
        Set<Field> unwrappedFields = ClassUtils.getAnnotatedFields(raw, GsonUnwrap.class);
        for (Field field : unwrappedFields) {
            AnnotatedType fieldType = GenericTypeReflector.getExactFieldType(field, type);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Object fieldValue = deserialize(json, fieldType.getType(), context);
                field.set(def, fieldValue);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        return def;
    }
}
```

It can then be registered globally via `new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Object.class, new UnwrappingDeserializer(new Gson())).create()` or for a specific type via `registerTypeAdapter`.

**Notes:**

- A real implementation should recursively check the entire class structure for the presence of `GsonUnwrap`, cache the result in a concurrent map, and only go through this procedure if it needs to. Otherwise it should just return `def` immediately
- It should also cache discovered annotated fields to avoid scanning the hierarchy each time
- `GenericTypeReflector` is coming from [GeAnTyRef](https://github.com/leangen/geantyref)
- `ClassUtils#getAnnotatedFields` is my own implementation, but it doesn't do anything special - it just gathers declared fields (via `Class#getDeclaredFields`) recursively for the class hierarchy
- `GsonUnwrap` is just a simple custom annotation

I presume a similar thing can be done for serialization as well. Examples linked from [Derlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295000/294657) can be a starting point.

Comment: excellent job, thanks! One little fix: I needed to change line `Object fieldValue = deserialize(json, fieldType.getType(), context);` to `Object fieldValue = context.deserialize(json, fieldType.getType());`