# How do I serialize a Dictionary items as flat properties of the class?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, gson

I have a class

```
public class Car {
    public String color = null;
    public String brand = null;
    public HashMap<String,String> attributes;

    public Car() {
        this.attributes  = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.color = "Red";
        car.brand = "Hyundai";
        car.attributes.put("key1", "value1");
        car.attributes.put("key2", "value1");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(car);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

This currently serializes my `car` object into

```
{"color":"Red","brand":"Hyundai","attributes":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value1"}}
```

But I would like to unpack and serialize the `attributes` Dictionary from `Car` class as individual properties rather dictionary. 
Ideally, i would like my json to be,

```
{"color":"Red","brand":"Hyundai","key1":"value1","key2":"value1"}
```

How do I achieve the same in GSON?

Comment: You could write a custom serializer to serialize the object to your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856937/gson-custom-serializer-in-specific-case/36979409

Comment: And then you need to maintain this serialiser and modify it every time you add a new attribute to your HashMap...

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294694/how-to-implement-a-gson-equivalent-of-jsonunwrap), there is no easy or straight forward way to achieve this.
If there is a scope of using `Jackson`, it can be achieved using `@JsonUnwrapped` but it doesn't work with Maps as explained [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/171)

but there is work around.

```
 @JsonIgnore
 public HashMap<String,String> attributes;

 @JsonAnyGetter
 public HashMap<String, String> getAttributes() {
    return attributes;
 }
```

And this will help create the required JSON.

```
(new ObjectMapper()).writeValueAsString(car)
```

Note. **This is an alternate approach**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JsonAnyGetter`on the getter of your `attributes`